# JS: Executing events overlapping in time afteranother

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I receive events on-the-fly in the correct order in which I want to process them after another (as well on-the-fly - so don't "store" them first).

The following example is not going to work as the function `someEventOccured()` could be called multiple times in a very close timespan. Thus, the execution of handleEvent would overlap in time (which I don't want). As I am writing to a file in `handleEvent()` I cannot have simultaneously execute the function and need to maintain the order...

```js
async someEventOccured(data:string){
   await handleEvent(data);
}
```

I have already tried using .then() and storing the promise, however I have no idea how to wait for the previous .then() to finish...

Your help is very appreciated <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to have a shared promise to queue onto:

```
let queue = Promise.resolve();
function someEventOccured(data:string) {
  queue = queue.then(() => {
    return handleEvent(data);
  }).catch(err => {
    // ensure `queue` is never rejected or it'll stop processing events
    // …
  });
}
```

Of course, this does implicitly store the `data` events in the closures on the promise chain.

Comment: what if handleEvent is async?

Comment: @MartinDallinger It will work, as its promise will be wrapped into the `.then`, that automatically awaits it...

Comment: @MartinDallinger `handleEvent` is expected to be asynchronous and return a promise, otherwise the whole queuing is pointless

Comment: Thank you - this makes sense now - I was just not used to the syntax and was a little confused as a result.