# Node.JS - awaiting tasks loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to handle requests one-by-one in javascript.

For example, we have 10 simultanious POST requests to the route `/wall/createPost` and following code:

```
app.post('/wall/createPost', (request, response) => {
    ...
    queue.push(request);
    ... somehow await to solve this and after make response.send('ok') ...
});
```

I need to make some queue to handle simillar tasks one-by-one. For example, loop.

```
let queue = [];

setInterval(() => {
    const dataToHandle = queue[0];
    ...
    queue.shift();
}, 1000);
```

How to await solvation of the task inside `app.post` callback?

Comment: could you write your code you have at the moment? i still have no idea what you want achieve

Comment: feels like a for..in loop is the right candidate to block each async request..but yea, not too sure what you're going after.

Comment: @LostJon yes, I need just this. How to make it in code, could you please explain?

Comment: You'll want to [queue the tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64955564/1048572). That doesn't mean you have to process them with `setInterval`